# Как сделать, чтоб флеш был ПОД определенным элементом?

Tags: flash, css

На странице сайта есть флешка. Когда открывается модальное окно, флешка перекрывает его, т.е. содержимое окна частично не видно.

Можно как-то исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убирается добавлением во флэш параметра

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```